# Edit Question name because Book Chapter name changed?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently working through Learn Python the Hard Way and I'm at exercise 42. I'm having some trouble with the exercise and was searching for help. I found out the chapters have been moved around a bit and chapter 42 used to be chapter 45. Current students will be searching for exercise 42.

The best SO question I found on this chapter is the following: [Learn Python the Hard Way 2nd Edition. Exercise 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976988/learn-python-the-hard-way-2nd-edition-exercise-45).

However, you only find it if you look for exercise 45. Should I edit the question name to the current correct name, so edit it to 42?

Comment: Just so you know, there are no "topics" or "threads" here. There are questions and there are answers.

Comment: @dandan78 Thank you, and done. I'm a bit confused why I'm getting downvotes. Is this question not appropriate here?

Comment: @MarijkeVonk voting on Meta can be a little confusing for users not experienced with meta.  Voting can be much more opinion based and can often me "agree" or "disagree", in addition to the usually reasons for voting.  Don't worry, votes on meta do not impact your reputation or your privileges.

Comment: @mar As psubsee2003 pointed out, the downvotes are probably to express disagreement with your proposal. Also note that the question you linked to would stand a good chance of getting closed as off-topic today because it is essentially a request for a code review.

Comment: Getting a good 'feel' for a new community takes some time, thanks for explaining @psubsee2003. I think I've figured the exercise out, is there any place my answer would be of value? Should I simply answer to the old question (even through it's considered off-topic nowadays), or what is the right way to go?

Comment: Rather than referring to an exercise number - which is only helpful if one indeed has exactly *that* version of the book - you may want to describe it in short. Put the exercise number not in your title (it does not mean a thing for those without the book!) but in a source reference, along with the edition and year of print of that book.